# Given -When-Then example with NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, bdd, nunit-2.5

Can anybody point me to some resources for Give-When-Then style of testing with NUnit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download, and add a reference to, [StoryQ](http://storyq.codeplex.com/), you can use a nice BDD style (see samples by clicking the link) and at the same time use NUnit as usual (and TestDriven.Net, R#'s runner, or what have you).

Answer (score 8):

The Given When Then style correlates closely to the Arrange Act Assert style for unit testing.

Here's an example:

```
[Test]
public void RotateAngle_Given27Degress_Returns64Degrees()
{
   //Arrange or Given
   var someAngleClass = new Angle();

   //Act or When
   var result = someAngleClass.Rotate(27);

   //Assert or Then
   Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(64));
}
```

The great thing about this testing style is you don't need to see the underlying code to understand the intent of the behavior.

For more info here are some sites:

http://www.arrangeactassert.com/

[Roy Osherove's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/default.aspx)

http://www.artofunittesting.com/

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but if you haven't already, you should check out [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/). It allows you to write the spec in clear text in a feature file. The tool will auto-generate NUnit tests based on the feature file.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check a small library
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Heleonix.Testing.NUnit/
Instead of writing comments like `//Arrange, //Act, //Assert` or naming unreadable methods like `Given_UserIsLoggedIn_When_SomeButtonIsPressed_Then_BlaBla` in you tests, the library provides ability to write tests in GWT and AAA styles in manner of JavaScript's Jasmine orJest. See Readme:
https://github.com/Heleonix/Heleonix.Testing/blob/master/README.md